# Verify my permissions in a MySQL database (or table)

Tags: mysql, database-permissions

In my job, I've been granted access to several databases, but not the same degree of liberty for each of them. A few minutes ago, I was attempting to make an `UPDATE` operation and I got this error message: `Error Code: 1142. UPDATE command denied to user 'clawdidr'@'192.168.1.105' for table 'test_table'`.
The DB Admin isn't around to give me the information I'm needing, so I've to figure it out by myself. So, the question that arises here is: Is there a way to verify on my own (with a query or something else) which databases or tables am I able to use for a `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` operations?

Comment: `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER`

Comment: SELECT Host, User FROM mysql.user; possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623390/mysql-database-permission-question

Comment: @Aguardientico Great, it worked. Put it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @AndaIancu, this is what I'm getting with your proposal: `Error Code: 1142. SELECT command denied to user 'clawdidr'@'192.168.1.105' for table 'user'`

Comment: Yes you do not have permission for mysql.user - show grant will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with: `SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER`